# Getting MessageID of outgoing message on TwiML reply to incomming message

Tags: twilio

I am trying to build a local database storing Twilio SMS message events.  There would be two tables: A Messages table with message info (To,From,Body,etc.), and a StatusRecords table containing status events (Status,ErrorCode,ErrorMessage, etc.).  Both tables would be keyed on the MessageID.

I can get the MessageID and message info when I send a message (as a client) using the REST API in the returned response.  That's fine.

I have a java servlet running that is called with status updates when Twilio updates the message delivery status.  I then update the status in my database using the MessageID as the key.  That's fine as well.

I have another servlet running that receives reply messages.  I pick up the reply MessageID and add this to the database.  This servlet also replies to the incomming message in the http GET response parameter using the TwilML API.

The problem is: How do I get the MessageID of the reply to the incomming message?  The reply takes place as a result of a response to the http GET.  I don't think I will hear from Twilio again after responding.

I assume that Twilio will update the status on the reply message as it is delivered or not delivered--and I will receive this update in my status update servlet.  I could probably try to match the phone number of the status update to get the reply MessageID but this seems sort of crude.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I see that I can use the Twilio Rest API to send a new message that will act as a reply.  And, in this situation I can pick up the new messages ID.  This may be the solution.  I wonder, from the SMS receivers standpoint, if there is any difference between a 'reply' message and a new message generated in this fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The `<Message>` verb takes an [`action`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message#attributes-action) parameter which lets you specify a URL for Twilio to request once it processes the Message noun.  This request will include the Message SID.

If you wanted to associate the SID of the incoming message with the one sent by Twilio, you could pass the incoming message SID as part of the URL you set for the action parameter:

```
http://example.com/message?id=XXXXXXXXXX
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Devin, I did read the documentation on the action parameter and I see how Twilio would send a http request to the URL.  The issue still is how would one associate the MessageID provided by this URL call to the message that was generated in the TwilML reply.  This would not be an issues if one were sending few messages but if multiple thread were sending messages, there would not be a direct association.  By using the REST API and sending a new message as a reply, there is no chance for ambiguity.  Of course, I am inexperienced here and I could be wrong.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: You could append the message sid of the inbound message to the URL you provide for the action parameter as a querystring value.  Eg action="http://example.com/message?id=XXXXXXXXXX"